# creating non existing method on an object in javascript

Tags: javascript

How do getter or setter works on object in javascript ?

i.e.

In python if I call a nonexistent method on an object I could intercept the call via getter and setter and in turn return from getter and setter.

How do I do similar functionality in JavaScript ?

https://github.com/Flotype/now/blob/master/lib/client/now.js implements this functionality somehow. I didn't understand the trick. can anyone explain ?

Comment: [\_\_defineGetter\_\_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineGetter)

Comment: @arxanas careful that's deprecated and only works in mozilla afaik

Comment: its non standard and deprecated, what about other methods ? ( or may be its not possible ? )

Comment: I don't think there are other methods currently, the main workaround is to access everything by a main `get` and `set` method which then does the checking inside that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the same functionality is virtually impossible in Javascript. My best guess would be something like this:

```
var getter = function (propName) { 
    if (propName in this) { 
        return this[propName]; 
    } else { 
        return "no prop"; 
    } 
};
```

You can call this function on any object you like using this syntax:

```
a = { "test": "yes" };
b = {}
console.log(getter.call(a, "test"));
console.log(getter.call(b, "test"));
```

It's not the best solution but I don't think there's a better way.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use non-standart mozilla [__noSuchMethod__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/noSuchMethod) property.

2) EcmaScript 6 Harmony propose the Proxy object. See [Simulating __noSuchMethod__](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aproxies&s=proxies%20cormac#simulating_nosuchmethod_doesnotunderstand)